# How to apply conditional decorator with arguments?

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I'm having trouble figuring this one out, and I keep getting a TypeError. I need a decorator to apply another decorator that takes arguments only if a condition holds. The TypeError has something to do with arguments being passed to the `outer()` method.

```
def decorator(foo, bar):
    def wrapped(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def outer():
            ...stuff with foo and bar...
            return func()
        return outer
    return wrapped


def conditional(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner():
        if some_condition:
            raise Error
        return decorator(1, 2)(func)
    return inner

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
@conditional
def login():
    ...
```

This generates `TypeError: outer() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`, but with some basic print statements (mainly `outer(*args), print(args)`) I find it is the following:

First positional:

`{'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'wsgi.input': <_io.BufferedReader name=964>, 'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>, 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'werkzeug.server.shutdown': <function WSGIRequestHandler.make_environ.<locals>.shutdown_server at 0x0000014341FCA0D0>, 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/0.14.1', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'PATH_INFO': '/login', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REMOTE_PORT': 54900, 'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1', 'SERVER_PORT': '5000', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:5000', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'python-requests/2.20.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Basic cGF1bDpmb29iYXI=', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '0', 'werkzeug.request': <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/login' [POST]>}`

Second positional:

`<function run_wsgi_app.<locals>.start_response at 0x0000014341FCA378>`

Somewhere my syntax sugaring is going wrong, not sure where.

By using `*args` that TypeErrror is resolved, but a new one appears:

`TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: How is `return wrapper` related to `def inner()` in `conditional()`? Should that be `return inner`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, typos were fixed.

Comment: Should the conditional be applied **once**, when importing, or **every time** the URL view function is called?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Every time the URL view is called.

Comment: Is the goal of the condition to not apply `decorator(1, 2)` at all if the condition is `True`?

Comment: Yes, if the condition holds an error should be thrown and `login()` not executed.

Comment: That’s not what I asked :-). Should the `decorator(1, 2)` or `decorator(1, 2)(func)` calls not take place then?

Comment: `decorator` et. all should not be called ever if the condition is True. I only want to use it as a conditional decorator if the condition is False.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning `outer`, without calling it, *as the result of a view call*. So Flask has to [treat this **as a view response**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#about-responses), and a response  that is not a string, a tuple or `Response` is seen as a WSGI object. The normal way a WSGI response is handled is by calling it as `<wsgi response>(environment, start_response)`.

You need to return the actual result of calling `outer()`.

This is what happens at module import time:

- `def login(): ...` is executed, creating a function object `login`.
- `@conditional` is applied as a decorator to `login`.

  - `def inner(): ...` is executed, creating a nested function with `func` in its closure. The `@wraps(func)` decorator attaches `func`'s name to `inner`
  - `return inner` returns `inner` to the caller
- `login = inner` is set as a result of `@conditional
- @app.route()`registers`inner`as the route handler for`/login`

This is what happens when you access `/login` via HTTP:

- Flask looks up the view function for `/login`, finds `inner`, calls it
- The `if condition:` test is false, skip to the next section
- `decorator(1, 2)` is called

  - `def wrapped(func): ...` is executed, creating an inner function with `foo` and `bar` in the closure
  - `return wrapped` returns to the caller
- `decorator(1, 2)...` is `wrapped...` so `wrapped(func)` is called

  - `def outer(): ...` is executed, creates an inner function with `func` in its closure. The `@wraps(func)` decorator attaches `func`'s name to `inner`.
  - `return outer` returns the `outer` function to the caller.
- `outer` is returned to the caller
- Flask is given `outer` as the response, which is treated as a WSGI object.

You are missing a final call here:

```
def conditional(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner():
        if some_condition:
            raise Error
        return decorator(1, 2)(func)()  # call the decorated `func()`
    return inner
```

However, unless you want the condition to prevent the `decorator(1, 2)` call from being applied, you want to *store the `decorator(1, 2)(func)` result*, instead of decorating it for each call:

```
def conditional(func):
    func = decorator(1, 2)(func)
    @wraps(func)
    def inner():
        if some_condition:
            raise Error
        return func()
    return inner
```

A middle ground could be to call only `decorator(1, 2)` once, to create the actual decorator function, once:

```
def conditional(func):
    dec = decorator(1, 2)
    @wraps(func)
    def inner():
        if some_condition:
            raise Error
        return dec(func)()
    return inner
```

Finally, consider passing along arguments passed to `inner()` to the decorated view function, so you can use `@condition` on view functions that accept route parameters:

```
def conditional(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if some_condition:
            raise Error
        return decorator(1, 2)(func)(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I follow where the `*args, **kwargs` would be coming from.

Comment: @pstatix: if you want to be able to use `@conditional` on *any* view function, then you'll have to handle views that take route parameters, like `@app.route('/foo/bar/<int:bar_id>')` where `bar_id` is then passed to the view function as a parameter. The function is then defined something like `def foo_bar(bar_id): ...`. The `inner()` function replaces `foo_bar`, and by giving it `*args, **kwargs` it'll accept any number of arguments, then pass those on to the wrapped function with the `(*args, **kwargs)` call.